# jQuery sortable and tinyMCE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce, tinymce-4

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e99xf/22/) - I'm using inline `tinymce plugin` to edit some text but at the same time I want those elements to be `sortable`.

I think that becouse both of those plugins use a lot of mouse events - initializing one of plugins make another break.

My point is to enable tinymce on click or select, and to be sortable on mouse delay (in fact anything that is at least a little intuitive will be ok)

Have you any idea?

I'm using tinymce 4

In included fiddle, if you turn off sorting, tiny will work.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. If anyone would need :

I've made it that way that sorting is on when CTRL is pressed only.

So just some simple keydown events with disabling tinymce and enabling again on keyup

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using the 'handle' setting for the Jquery UI sortable element solves this issue.